# Redirection of Director and all sublinks to a new subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

1 -- I'm looking to redirect like so:

http://domain.com/place to http://sub.domain.com/place

... and I'd like it to happen even if you do the following (for all sublinks):

http://domain.com/place/another to http://sub.domain.com/place/another.

2 -- I'd like to redirect similarly, but with a slight variation:

http://domain.com/place to http://domain.com/between/place

Again, I would like whatever comes after /place to be the same after the redirect to connect to the right place.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: That will not work. You can't redirect the same URL to two different places. You want `http://www.domain.com/place` to go to a subdomain and also to `http:/domain.com/between/place`. You need to choose one redirect.

Comment: Clarification: in option 1 & option 2 "place" is different. They aren't the same string. 

option 1: domain.com/myplace to sub.domain.com/myplace
option 2: domain.com/newplace to domain.com/a/newplace